# parsing strings with non alphanumeric characters in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am relatively new to Python, but here it goes...

My program imports a string from a json file, say for example "#python is #great".

I am trying to parse the string so for each occurrence of "#" it prints out the word following until it gets to a non alphanumeric character like a space or "=". So in this example it prints: #python #great

The code I have so far is:

```
with open("tweet.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
#opens my twitter file

def find_all(s, ch):
return [i for i, letter in enumerate(s) if letter == ch]

tags = find_all(data, "#")
length = len(tags)
#finds all occurrences of the "#" character
```

Up until here it all runs fine, but inside this loop it won't work unfortunately.

```
for x in range (0, length):

items = data[tags[x]:data.find('^\W+$')]
print items
x += 1
```

It also cuts of the final character too. I'm really stuck on this so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re.findall(r'#\w+', data)
```

`\w` is for matching `[A-Za-z_0-9]` or all alphanumeric characters.

Comment: it should be `\w+` not `/w+`

Answer (score 2):

regex seems like the ideal solution here

```
print re.findall("#[a-zA-Z]+",data)
```

Comment: needs a \d for alphanumeric.

Comment: You can also use complement character sets to specify what characters are your end of word markers (it may be easier depending on the job you're looking at doing).  Something like this:  print re.findall("#[^\s=]+",data) which matches one or more of any character that's *not* a space or =

Comment: @dementedhedgehog I can not predict what the character at the end of the "#" will be. So I figured using all non-alphanumeric characters would be a safer way to go.

Comment: Yep.  Maybe I've not been completely clear.  One way or another you need to decide what the acceptable character set is for your words.  e.g.  #abc, #Abc1, #a$x-k_d  are all *potentially* acceptable solutions depending on the problem definition.  There are two ways of describing the set of acceptable characters in regex.. you can either do it constructively by listing all the characters that are allowed, but you can also do it by saying what characters are not acceptable.  I just think it is nice to know that you have a choice as sometimes it's simpler to say what characters you don't want.